# Create ansible groupvars from group_vars as dict

Tags: ansible

## What's wrong here?

hosts.yml

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    computenode[1:2]:
  children:
    computenodes:
      hosts:
        computenode[1:2]:
    net_192_168_99:
      children:
        computenodes:
    net_192_168_123:
      children:
        computenodes:
```

group_vars/net_192_168_99.yml

```
---
network:
  net_addr: 99
```

group_vars/net_192_168_123.yml

```
---
network:
  net_addr: 123
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Foo playbook 
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: false
   tasks:
    - name: Debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ groups[item] | map('extract', hostvars, 'network') | list }}"
      loop: "{{ groups | select('match','net_.*') | list }}"
```

I would expect to see `net_addr: 123` somewhere in the output but what I get is always `net_addr: 99`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What troubleshooting steps have you already tried, and what was their outcome?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? => [How variables are merged](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-variables-are-merged). I.E. Unless you manually play arround with `ansible_group_priority`, you will always get the same result AND you will never get both results anyway.

Comment: As far as I understand there is no concept of group_vars in the gathered facts. They all get merged to hostvars as described in the link @Zeitounator provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I came up with this approach for having groupvars as I expect them. I took the parts of the answer from a lot of sources which I'm pitiful not able to name in detail any more.

hosts.yml

```
---
all:
  hosts:
    computenode[1:2]:
  children:
    computenodes:
      hosts:
        computenode[1:2]:
    net_192_168_99:
      children:
        computenodes:
    net_192_168_123:
      children:
        computenodes:
...
```

group_vars/net_192_168_99.yml

```
---
net_addr: 99
net_mask: 24
...
```

group_vars/net_192_168_123.yml

```
---
net_addr: 123
net_mask: 24
...
```

playbook.yml

```
---
- name: Debug playbook 
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  become: false

  vars:
    groupvars: {}

  tasks:
    - name: Load groupvars
      include_tasks: loadvars.yml
      vars:
        group_name: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ groups | select('match','net_.*')| list }}"
    - name: List groupvars
      debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      become: false
      loop: "{{ groupvars | list }}"
      when: item is defined
    - name: Create from template
      template:
        src: debug.j2
        dest: debug.txt
...
```

loadvars.yml

```
---
- name: Check if file exist in group_vars
  stat:
    path: group_vars/{{ group_name }}.yml
  register: result
- name: Load vars if exist
  include_vars:
    file: group_vars/{{ group_name }}.yml
    name: "{{ group_name }}"
  become: false
  when: result.stat.exists
  register: foo
- name: Add to groupvars{}
  set_fact:
    groupvars: "{{ groupvars | combine(foo.ansible_facts) }}"
    cacheable: yes
  become: false
  when: result.stat.exists
...
```

templates/debug.j2

```
{% for item in groupvars|dict2items %}
{{ item.key }}
{% for inner in item.value|dict2items %}
{{ inner.key }} {{ inner.value }}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```